# Adding confirmation before performing "Confirm Shipment"

Tags: acumatica

Our current customization request from a customer has the need to add a confirmation message based on some logic to the Shippers screen before the confirm shipment process is allowed to occur.

My first thought was to override the default "ConfirmShipment" method with the check routines and if the confirmation is clear to proceed with the stock confirmation logic.

Below is a snippit of the code being used:

```
    [PXOverride]
    public virtual void ConfirmShipment(SOOrderEntry docgraph, SOShipment shiporder, ConfirmShipmentDelegate confirmdelegate)
    {
                var baseConfirm = true;
                WebDialogResult result = Base.Document.View.Ask(Messages.ShippingConfirmation, MessageButtons.YesNo);
                if (result == WebDialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    baseConfirm = false;
                }

               if (baseConfirm)
               {
                   confirmdelegate(docgraph,shiporder);
               }
     }
```

The override functionality does work and I get my confirmation prompt however after selecting the "Yes/No" prompts, the code execution exits.   The check on result == WebDialogResult is not even called.  I believe this might be caused by the method is being triggered from a long running operation which is aborted by the dialog result.

My second thought was to override the "Action"  method and handle the checks before the ConfirmShipment method is even called.

When attempting this using the sample method below, the Delegate is always returning null

```
    //[PXOverride]
    //[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Actions", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
    //[PXButton]
    //public virtual IEnumerable Action(PXAdapter adapter,
    //        [PXInt]
    //        [PXIntList(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }, new string[] { "Confirm Shipment", "Create Invoice", "Post Invoice to IN", "Apply Assignment Rules", "Correct Shipment", "Create Drop-Ship Invoice", "Print Labels", "Get Return Labels", "Cancel Return", "Print Pick List" })]
    //        int? actionID,
    //        [PXString()]
    //        string ActionName,
    //        Func<PXAdapter,int?,string,IEnumerable> actiondelegate
    //        )
    //{
```

With both / either of the above in mind, what would the best way to intercept the "ConfirmShipment" action to add a webdialog confirmation before running the stock methods.   Is there a way to work around the long runnign process issue in confirmshipment or is there another issue that is preventing that from returning correctly?

Any assistance/direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Below code works. How ever i am unable to read the ActionName, but action id seems correct in this case. :s

```
 public PXAction<SOShipment> action;
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Actions", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
        [PXButton]
        protected virtual IEnumerable Action(PXAdapter adapter,
            [PXInt]
            [PXIntList(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }, new string[] { "Confirm Shipment", "Create Invoice", "Post Invoice to IN", "Apply Assignment Rules", "Correct Shipment", "Create Drop-Ship Invoice", "Print Labels", "Get Return Labels", "Cancel Return", "Print Pick List" })]
            int? actionID,
            [PXString()]
            string ActionName
            )
        {
            if (actionID == 1)
            {
                var baseConfirm = false;
                WebDialogResult result = Base.Document.View.Ask("confirm?", MessageButtons.YesNo);
                if (result == WebDialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    baseConfirm = true;
                }

                if (baseConfirm)
                {
                    return Base.action.Press(adapter);
                }
                else
                    return adapter.Get();
            }
            else
                return Base.action.Press(adapter);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Hybridzz.   In the end that's what I had except for the return adapter.Get().... it was either that or just restarting IIS that finally kicked it off.